# Box2d - how to grab and throw objects

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

Say there are 3 boxes on the screen, how can I go about touching one of them to pick it up and "throw" it at the others? I have the rest of the world implemented but can't find much information on how to grab/drag/toss physics objects. Any sample code or documentation out there that would help with this?

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you are attempting to do. It is a physics simulation and as such a typical way of interacting with the system is by applying forces to objects opposed to direct manipulation of the x,y coordinates.  But you can in fact do either.  I believe the most common approach is to use a mouse joint. A google search on b2MouseJoint will show the documentation and several examples including this one.

http://muhammedalee.wordpress.com/tag/b2mousejoint/

Comment: For the mouse joint the doc says "Users often want to achieve precise positioning and instantaneous response. The mouse joint doesn’t work very well in that context. You may wish to consider using kinematic bodies instead." I want the object to respond immediately to where the touch is moved so I don't think the mouse joint will work. I guess I have to make the body kinematic but can you change a body back and forth between dynamic and kinematic? I still want it to interact with other bodies.

Comment: yes, you can change it from kinematic to dynamic and adjust the position directly but you may not see the response from the collisions you want given that a kinematic bodies have infinite mass. It's never simple to do this kind of interaction because you need to play well with the physics engine but you can achieve a lot of different things. I would try swapping dynamic/kinematic on touch and seeing how you feel about that.

Comment: will try this out. Upvoting for now. Still open to other suggestions.